# Angular Material 2 autocomplete and select combined?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to make an input form with Angular Material 2, to search through items in an inventory. Therefore I would like an autocomplete-like input field where you can search through your inventory.

But the problem is (as I understand) that if you e.g. type in something which is not in your inventory, the field will still accept it. Whereas the select field has the capability of only offering the listed options but is not searchable.

I thought of adding a validator on the autocomplete, but as far as I know, it is not possible to validate against an array. 
Does anybody know how to solve this problem? It seems to me like a pretty usual task, but I haven't come across any similar posts.

Comment: You could add a default option to your md-autocomplete.

Comment: @mjrdnk I'm not entirely sure what you mean? Do you mean a default md-option? If yes, how would this hinder a user typing in an invalid object? Please tell if something is unclear, I will gladly elaborate :)